# How do I resolve DNS issues?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, dns

This may be a completely stupid question, but here goes. I've been having issues with my network. This is not an ISP problem, since the internet works perfectly on my mac partition and on the other computers in my house. The internet on Ubuntu works intermittently, and once I have gained access to a sever, I can continue navigating on that server without issue. But when I try to access other servers, about half of the time the server cannot be found. Restarting my wifi will sometimes resolve the issue temporarily, sometimes it will not. Because other computers and partitions operate without issue, I am fairly confident this is a software issue in Ubuntu.Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a DNS problem, why don't you try changing the DNS provider? By default, most of the routers act themselves as DNS providers, you could try to change to any of the avaliable on the net, like 8.8.8.8 (google).

[image]

You can change it in network manager settings, editing the connection you are using (wireless or cable) and under IPv4 parameters adding the DNS ip on the box.

[image]

Good luck!